# The following command produced analyzer issues: Analyze RNFIRMessaging.m

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I try to execure `react-native run-ios`, but here is what I get :

> > ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following commands produced analyzer issues:
>       Analyze RNFIRMessaging.m
>   (1 command with analyzer issues)
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC /Volumes/3/Github/PROJECT/DevSummit/app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNFIRMessaging.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFIRMessaging.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFIRMessaging.o RNFIRMessaging.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app
>   An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

How to tackle this error?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting `ios/build` directory and re-running `react-native run-ios`

Comment: Solved for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to this by running `react-native upgrade`.